# PreferenceFragmentCompat setting the theme

Tags: android

Beginner coder here.

I am using `PreferenceFragmentCompat` to make a preference fragment that I can use with getSupportFragmentManager().

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T

I am following the directions there, except I'm not sure how to set the preferenceTheme. My app crashes when I click on the settings menu with this exception is thrown

`IllegalStateException: Must specify preferenceTheme in theme.`

Where do I set the theme?

Answer (score 4):

In values/styles.xml you have to add:
`<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```